# EE Calendar Sorting Function by category

Tags: calendar

I'm trying to sort the Solspace calendar by category. The categories are set up and I have a dropdown in the monthly calendar. Each category will display a category # in the class file for example category7. I just can't get the dropdown to sort the categories once selected.

--Filter by Category--
                    {exp:channel:categories channel="calendar_categories"}
                        {category_name}
                    {/exp:channel:categories}

Answer (score 0):

I've done this by adding the category as a css class to the events. Then you can use your dropdown menu to filter with js/jquery.